# How to get BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission to auto pair device in a routed device without putting it at system app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions, android-permissions

I need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission to autopair device

How to get BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission to autopair device in a roted device 
without putting it at system app ?

I am trying to make a programmatically auto repair with one devices that I have already displayed in ListView without showing the "Pair Dialog"

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST");
        registerReceiver(new PairingRequest(), filter);
```

//receiver

```
public static class PairingRequest extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public PairingRequest() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST")) {
            try {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                int pin = intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY", 0);
                //the pin in case you need to accept for an specific pin
                Log.d("PIN", " " + intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY",0));
                //maybe you look for a name or address
                Log.d("Bonded", device.getName());
                byte[] pinBytes;
                pinBytes = (""+pin).getBytes("UTF-8");
                device.setPin(pinBytes);
                device.setPairingConfirmation(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but after is calling  `device.setPairingConfirmation(true);` it goes on exception with this error `java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission: Neither user 10069 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.`

I have made my search and all the suggestions was to put the app in system/app but I can't put there cause I need to make updates in the future.

My device that I am using is rooted and the app is in "data/app" path

Any suggestion would be an help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: docs state - "This is not available to third party applications".  I assume you'd need your app to be signed with the same key as the device platform and added to privileged permission whitelist - https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist

Comment: @MarkKeen thank u, I will take a look on privileged permission whitelist

Comment: I don't think you'll get away without it being in the priv-app folder though, regardless of being rooted ..